# Insert from SQL shell script

Tags: sql, shell, scripting, sh

Good evening

I am trying to insert data from one table to another in my script and it comes up with database not found - have I done something wrong?

```
mysql -e INSERT INTO mysql.db SELECT * from "$cpuser"_mysql.db;
```

CPUser is a variable manually assigned earlier in the script.

From the CLI I can select * from both

Output from comment;

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''domain7mysql4'_mysql.db' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''domain7mysql4'_mysql.user' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-se expects a string, so you need to provide one

```
mysql -e "INSERT INTO mysql.db SELECT * from `${cpuser}_mysql`.db;"
```

or

```
mysql -e "INSERT INTO mysql.db SELECT * from ${cpuser}_mysql.db;"
```

if there are no reserved text

Comment: This appears to then show a sytax error - see edited post

Comment: i corrected my answer

Comment: Use `${cpuser}_mysql` to avoid trying to expand a parameter named `cpuser_mysql`. The placement of the quotation marks in the original prevent this error.